# method or data member not found on Outlook object

Tags: vba, outlook

Like the subject line says, I'm getting this silly error message "Method or data memeber not found" on the following code.  I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it.  It's probably something stupid right?  Where I'm creating my variables, you'll notice one named tempMailItem.  It is of type Outlook.MailItem.  When I click on the dot operator, MailItem is one of the members.  But when I type the dot operator on the Outlook object where I'm making the cast, suddenly MailItem is not one of the members of that object.  I don't get that!  What's going on?

Alan

```
Sub MoveHarpStatMail()

Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
Dim olappns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oitem As Object
Dim ItemsToProcess As Outlook.Items
Dim myFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim sFilter As String
Dim tempMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

On Error GoTo LocalErr

'set outlook objects
Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
Set olappns = olapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = olappns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'Filter or only MailItems received today
sFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= " & AddQuotes(Format(Date, "ddddd"))
Set ItemsToProcess = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Restrict(sFilter)

For Each oitem In ItemsToProcess
 If TypeName(oitem) = "MailItem" Then
   Set tempMailItem = DirectCast(oitem, Outlook.MailItem) '<<<< Problem is here with Outlook object
   If CheckSubject(tempMailItem.Subject) Then
     MoveToArchiveFolder (tempMailItem)
  End If
 End If
Next oitem

ExitProc:
Set olapp = Nothing
Set olappns = Nothing
Set myFolder = Nothing
Set ItemsToProcess = Nothing

Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Directcast` in VBA. Use:

```
Set tempMailItem = oitem
```